# Text rotation 270 degrees not works in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rotation, internet-explorer-7

I am creating a slide menu with one label text rotated by 270 degrees. Works well in all modern browsers including Explorers 10+9. But I'd like to make it functional also in older IE8 & IE7, so added the filter definition recommended in many answers here on SO, but it doesn't work. Tested the page with IE developer tools switched to IE8 browser (in IE8 standards mode).

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mJA7/) + [its preview](http://jsfiddle.net/8mJA7/show).

CSS

```css
.menu p.heading {
    position:absolute;
    right:-22px;
    top:3em;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Tried to add/remove quotes to the filter, changed html5 doctype to xhtml, but nothing seems to work. Can somebody give me an advice on how to set it right for IE 8 & 7 ?

And then also one subsidiary question: is there any advantage to separate those two IE8-specific definitions in a separated tag [as shown here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/9b21a3c2-6bdf-4aad-a90d-868bdeb3d866#88077185-5d18-46fe-b9f2-5e1c34ba86a2)?

```css
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
.rotation {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks for any hints !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rotation seems to be working in IE8. However the rotated item is positioned incorrectly, so the rotated text is off the edge of the screen when you first view the page. It does show up when you hover and the box moves into view.

This is because IE8's `filter` style has a different rotation point from the standard CSS. It uses the top-left corner as the rotation point, whereas CSS defaults to the center. You'll need to modify one or other of them so that they use the same point. Then once you've positioned it correctly, it'll look the same in all browsers.

This isn't actually that easy to do -- in IE, you'll need to use a completely different rotation filter with complex matrix maths rather than the relatively easy `rotation=3` that you have now -- so my recommendation would be to use a javascript polyfill called [CSSSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) to make IE8 and earlier recognise the standard CSS rotation - it'll use the `filter` internally, but all you need is `-sand-rotate(-90deg);` alongside the other standard CSS variants.

This will make your code much easier to work with, and it'll work consistently across browsers.

To answer your second question -- yes, if you're using `filter` to do rotations, then it would be a good idea to put the `filter` styles in an IE<=8 specific block, because they interfere with IE9.

IE9 supports the standard CSS rotation, but also works with the filter, so in IE9 as things stand, you're getting both rotations, which is making it go completely wrong. (you end up with graphical corruption; it's not pretty).

However, if you're using CSS Sandpaper as I suggested above, then this point is irrelevant because it will detect which IE version you're on, and won't run in IE9, so in that case you won't need IE8-specific stylesheets.

Comment: Thank you very much Spudley for the explanation, that CSSSandpaper library looks to be very handy to fix it. Surely will use it in my template. I tested the page in Explorer 10's developer tools switched to IE8 mode, but the text was not rotated. Can you please also tell me (seems like that filter was ignored), how to test the page for IE8 properly? Thank you.

Comment: yes, that's right -- IE10's compat mode doesn't do the `filter`s. It's not really fully "compatible". You need to use a real copy of IE8 to test (and use `X-UA-Compatible` with `IE=edge` to make sure that later versions don't use compat mode).

Comment: Perfect, just tested the page on my old PC with IE8 and there the text is rotated (as expected) and also displaced (as foretold). Until now I used to test my pages also in [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and in this time I was confused when the page rendered differently in IE10's developer tools than in IETester. I don't have an in-depth view on this browser behaviour. Well, thanks for this great tip, will use the CSSSandpaper to fix it. Best regards

Comment: Yeah, compat mode really isn't compatible enough to make it a good testing tool in most cases. One thing you might want to try is http://www.browserstack.com/ - it gives you a full working copy of pretty much any browser/version/os you could want to test. It is a paid service, but it's well worth it if you test a lot. (plus Microsoft are currently giving a 3 month subscription away free via their http://www.modern.ie/ site)

Comment: The web development is my hobby, i am not a professional designer (at least currently). Anyway that modern.ie seems like a handy informative service, tested my site and found a problem with **responsive design** (or a suggested enhancement). Looks to be a hot topic nowadays, so i must have a closer look at this. :-)